# how to read specific line from the text file in C#

Tags: c#

how to read particular line (for eg line no 2) from the text file in C#.

abc.txt is the filename contains 
line 1- xyz
line 2- pqr

I want to read pqr from abc.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] stringArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\abc.txt");
string line1 = stringArray[0];
string line2 = stringArray[1];//This is the one you want
string line3 = stringArray[2];
```

Comment: It would be useful to the OP and the community in general if you could please explain **how** and **why** your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] stringArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\abc.txt");

// Array starts from 0 so basically the first position is 0.

// So I thought of a myb not bad idea
// You can say e.g. pqr is at the line no 2 and then you'll need to subtract - 1
// and that will be your index also rqy is on position 2 - 1 = index[1].

// Myb my explanation isn't the best but i've tried.

string line1 = stringArray[0]; // index 0
string line2 = stringArray[1]; // index 1
string line3 = stringArray[2]; // index 2
```